# How to set file uploaded via API as Public in Infusionsoft?

Tags: infusionsoft

I tried using Data Table api but I get "AccessDenied" error for FileBox table.

> [NoTableAccess]Access denied to table FileBox

Does Infusionsoft not allow updating fields of FileBox table?
Is there any other way to set files as Public?

Answer (score 0):

In order to upload a file to FileBox you need to use  [FileService.uploadFile](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#file-upload-a-file) API method.

Call to [FileService.getDownloadUrl](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#file-retrieve-a-file-download-url) will return you public URL of a file.

Please note file ID is returned on FileService.uploadFile method call. You can use this ID when requesting URL of a file by FileService.getDownloadUrl method call.

You cannot change Public field value (as any others in FileBox table), because they have [read access only](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/table-schema/).

Comment: I can not get Download URL for file uploaded via API. It throws an error saying that file is not public.

Comment: What I'm not trying to do is call getFile to get base64encoded data and then create a file out of it. But the generated file is corrupted. Not sure how to fix that.

Comment: There was an issue with the way I was decoding it.
I now decode the data, create a file and store it on S3 and return S3 url to user which is valid for 24 hrs and then file is automatically removed from S3.